# Como reiniciar numeracion de un id que va a entrando a una tabla

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo una tabla donde en cada registro que meto, se agrega un id pero cuando borro un id y cuando quireo agregar otro no se reinicia.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ese es el comportamiento que tienen las columnas Identity, no es necesario recuperar el id que se pierde.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lo que necesitas es el siguiente script:

```
  DBCC CHECKIDENT('Plantillaid' , RESEED, 0)
```

donde está el 0 puedes modificar para que se resetee al valor que tu digas

Comment: Lo copie tal y como esta a excepción del nombre de la tabla claro, pero me dice que en el parametro 2 es incorrecto en el DBCC statement.

Comment: el nombre del campo va entre comillas simples  ' nombre '

Comment: DBCC CHECKIDENT('Plantillaid' , RESEED, 0)

Comment: Gracias,  ya pude pero en ves de plantillaid, era el nombre de la tabla

Comment: excelente que bueno que pudiste solucionarlo